# Downward Trends in SQL Interest

Tags: mysql

[image]

According to these trends, there were several dips in interest regarding SQL management systems. What was the cause of these dips?

Comment: Xmas holidays https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=today%205-y&geo=US&q=mysql,postgresql&hl=en

Comment: How do you measure "interest"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple -- During the Christmas holidays, programmers, even companies, work less.

What puzzles me is the meaning of "interest".  Did they explain it?

Comment: Not sure how that skipped my mind. I don't like how I overlook simple things like this.